# Correct C# conversion counterpart for VB's CTYPE()

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, ado.net

The below is a snippet from VB that I am porting to a C# rewrite.  My question is what is `receipt_date` after the assignment?  Is it still an `object` or is it a `string`?

```
Dim receipt_date As Object
receipt_date = CType(dr.Item("RECTDT"), String)
```

Would this be the correct C# counterpart?

```
object receipt_date;
receipt_date = dr["RECTDT"].ToString();
```

After both of these execute would the **VB** version, `receipt_date` be equal to the **C#** version?  If not, what do I need to do to make it so?  Thanks

Comment: You realize that your VB.NET code casts to a `String` then casts back to an `Object`, right?

Comment: @Randolpho: No, his VB.NET code casts to a `String` and assigns that value to an `Object` variable; it's not a cast.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you would end up with the same result. It's semantically different from the VB version (you're calling `ToString()` explicitly instead of using `CType`, which is loosely equivalent to a cast in C#), but it's functionally identical. It's also safer, since casting a null value in the database (which would be `DBNull` in the runtime) would throw an exception.

Just for the sake of being comprehensive, though, the actual C# counterpart would be this:

```
var receipt_date = (string)dr["RECTDT"];
```

As a point of style, though, try to avoid implicit typing (i.e., using the `var` keyword instead of saying `string` or `int`) for simple types. `var` is useful when the type might change in the future (and isn't important), or if the type is long and/or complex and `var` makes it more readable. In this instance, I would suggest:

```
string receipt_date = (string)dr["RECTDT"];
```

Comment: I'll +1 you even though I disagree with you about when to use `var`. Learn to love `var`.

Comment: @Randolpho: It's a matter of style; there's been loads of discussion about it on SO. Neither way is correct in any technical sense.

Comment: @Adam Robinson: See Edit for my miss-type.  I didn't write the VB portion and I am trying to figure out is what **TYPE** `receipt_date` is after assigning the value to it.  Does it make it a String?  I am not familiar with VB so I am cautious as to what `CTYPE` is doing.

Comment: Careful with that cast, it is *not* a substitute for CType().  CType does value conversions.

Comment: @Refracted: `CType` is essentially VB's cast operator (though `DirectCast` is a better analog for a cast, but that's not the point). The type of `receipt_date` in the VB example is `object`, but it contains a value that is of type `String`.

Comment: @Hans: There is no direct analog for a C# cast in VB.NET; `CType` performs conversions that go beyond what the type might define, and `DirectCast` performs *no* conversions (closer to the actual IL cast opcode).

Comment: @Adam: So HOW would I rewrite that in C#?

Comment: @Refracted: I would go with your original code (using `ToString()`), as casting a value that's null in the database (meaning it would be `DBNull` in the runtime) would cause an exception.

Comment: @Adam: Didn't mean to sound dense I just wanted to double check with all the other convo going on.

Comment: Convert.ToString() does a lot that CType() does.  About as much as you'd want it to.

Comment: @Adam: Cool, that was going to be a follow up question, "How is `.ToString()` different from `(string)`".  Thanks for the pre-emptive answer.

Comment: @Adam: oh, I agree; it's all style. I'm just sayin'... learn to love `var`.

Comment: I'd also recommend `Convert.ToString()` as a better (i.e. closer) replacement to `CType`. Perhaps not in this case, but in general.

Comment: @Pavel: Yes, in cases where the object could be an actual `null` reference, then `Convert.ToString()` eliminates the need for that check (as would `string.Format`, though we're splitting hairs here).

Answer (score 2):

VB's `CType` keyword is more or less equivalent to `Convert.ToString` though not exactly the same.

So the following in VB...

```
Dim receipt_date As Object 
receipt_date = CType(dr.Item("RECTDT"), String)
```

...would be best (or most closely) translated to the following in C#.

```
object receipt_date;
receipt_date = Convert.ToString(dr.Item["RECTDT"]);
```

By the way `CType(..., String)` gets compiled into `Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Conversions.ToString`.