# What is the C# equivalent to VB.NET's CType Function for use with generic types?

Tags: c#, vb.net, generics, casting, type-conversion

Assume I have a table called `MyTable` in a SQL Server database called `MyDB` with the following three records:

```
|ID|MyVarcharColumn|
--------------------
|1|123|
|2|2014-10-01 9:58 AM|
|3|True|
```

Now assume I have the following VB.NET code:

```
Public Shared Sub Test()
    Dim myIntValue As Integer = GetValue(Of Integer)(1)
    Dim myDateValue As Date = GetValue(Of Date)(2)
    Dim myBooleanValue As Boolean = GetValue(Of Boolean)(3)
End Sub

Public Shared Function GetValue(Of T)(ByVal id As Integer) As T
    Dim ds As System.Data.DataSet = GetSQLDataSet(String.Format("SELECT MyVarcharColumn FROM MyTable WHERE ID={0}", id))
    Return CType(ds.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("MyVarcharColumn"), T)
End Function

Public Shared Function GetSQLDataSet(ByVal ForQuery As String) As DataSet
    GetSQLDataSet = New DataSet()
    Dim conn As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("Data Source=MyDBServer;Initial Catalog=MyDB;Integrated Security=True")
    Dim cmd As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(ForQuery, conn)
    conn.Open()
    Dim da As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
    da.Fill(GetSQLDataSet)
    conn.Close()
End Function
```

I can call `Test()` and everything runs fine.  Notably, the use of VB.NET's `CType` function somehow succeeds in *converting* (not *casting*, because the underlying database column value is a string) into the correct type.

Now if I'm to believe things like [Correct C# conversion counterpart for VB's CTYPE()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3231049/correct-c-sharp-conversion-counterpart-for-vbs-ctype) and [How do I translate VB.Net's CType() to C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12249528/how-do-i-translate-vb-nets-ctype-to-c-sharp), I should be able to use the following C# code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int myIntValue = GetValue<int>(1);
    DateTime myDateValue = GetValue<DateTime>(2);
    bool myBooleanValue = GetValue<bool>(3);
}

static T GetValue<T>(int id)
{
    System.Data.DataSet ds = GetSQLDataSet(String.Format("SELECT MyVarcharColumn FROM MyTable WHERE ID={0}", id));
    return (T)ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["MyVarcharColumn"];
}

public static System.Data.DataSet GetSQLDataSet(string forQuery)
{
    System.Data.DataSet ret = new System.Data.DataSet();
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection conn = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("Data Source=MyDBServer;Initial Catalog=MyDB;Integrated Security=True");
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand cmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(forQuery, conn);
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter da = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    conn.Open();
    da.Fill(ret);
    conn.Close();
    return ret;
}
```

However, I'm getting an error at runtime that fails on `return (T)ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["MyVarcharColumn"];` saying "Specified cast is not valid".

I understand that I'm not casting because the return type is a string, so what I actually need is a conversion.  In VB.NET, the `CType` function serves both roles; however, in C#, it would seem I'm stuck using one of the explicitly-typed conversion functions like `Convert.ToInt32()`.  Since I'm dealing with a generic type here, that doesn't work.

I guess if I could boil this down into a single question, it would be: in C#, how do I convert a string to a generic type like VB.NET's `CType` does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you *only* need to support a very specific set of types that are supported by it, then [`Convert.ChangeType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dtb69x08(v=vs.110).aspx) may be okay:

```
object value = (string) ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["MyVarcharColumn"];
return (T) Convert.ChangeType(value, typeof(T));
```

You might want to consider specifying a format provider as well. I would *strongly* encourage you to avoid this sort of code though. What representation are you expecting for `double` values, for example? What about `DateTime`? Ideally, you would have these stored in different columns in SQL so that you could avoid having to do any conversion yourself - but if you *must* use a string, I'd probably make it very explicit for both the formatting and parsing, e.g. using ISO-8601 format for `DateTime` values. Your current approach makes it very fragile to cultural issues.

I'd also strongly advise you to stop building SQL dynamically. Even for integers it's not ideal as you're not specifying the format provider, but using parameterized SQL in *all* cases is just a good habit to get into.

Comment: Thanks Jon.  I do only have a very specific set of types that are supported, and doubles are not currently included.  It's obviously a work in progress though, ripe for refactoring if and when its scope grows.  I know that in many contexts this approach is fragile, but I don't have an issue with that here.  And, I knew I was going to get the lecture about parameterized SQL :) I was being lazy building the sample code for the post and thought I could get away with it because of the integer (i.e. no risk of SQL injection).

Comment: @roryap: "No risk of SQL injection" That depends on whether you've got devious users: http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2014/08/08/the-bobbytables-culture. Even if `double` isn't an issue, `DateTime` could cause you huge problems. It would be a lot clearer if you used an ISO-8601 format everywhere IMO.